# DataTable v1.9 query string not binding to ASP.NET MVC method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular-datatables

I notice DataTable's query string is pretty large with all the values like sEcho, iColumns, etc. However it's not binding to my object parameter in ASP.NET MVC, but it all seems to be because of the last value in the query string DataTable is sending over which is:

```
&_=15646516541564
```

If I remove this the data binding works fine. What is this? What can I do about this? Why is the name of it just an underscore? It makes sense why the data binding is failing since _ isn't a valid variable name in C#, but how can I get around this as DataTable 1.9.3 seems to be the one sending this over to me.